# In what file is the event-handler wiring stored in VS2010 WPF application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, event-handling, code-behind

In Visual Studio 2010 Designer, if you press [F4] while the WPF MainWindow has focus, you get a Properties view. If you click on the Events tab, and then double-click "Loaded", a handler for the window's Loaded event is automatically created in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

but where is the "wiring" code that attaches this handler to the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will notice that in MainWindow.xaml there is Loaded attribute on window node which points to your event handling method:

```
<Window ... Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    ...
</Window>
```

That is how xaml parser knows what method to wire up

Comment: You can find the actual handler being attached in the autogenerated MainWindow.g.i.cs file.